# How do I convert "HH:MM" format string to Timestamp in Java?

Tags: java, string, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a string `09:28.` and I want to convert this string to `Timestamp` object.

Below is my coding:

```java
Object d = getMappedObjectValue(reportBeamDataMap, ReportBeamConstant.DAT_STOPDATE);
Date stopDate1 = (Date)d;
SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String timeString = printFormat.format(stopDate1);
```

Now I want above `String` as `Timestamp` (only HH:MM). How to do that?

Comment: why not convert `stopDate1` to `TimeStamp` instead of `timeString ` ?

Comment: Beacuse stopDate1 has date and other time data as well. And i want only HH:MM. So i took them out in a string first. But nevermind,                 Object d1 = getMappedObjectValue(reportBeamDataMap, ReportBeamConstant.DAT_STOPDATE);
Date stopDate12 = (Date)d1;
SimpleDateFormat printFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String timeString1 = printFormat.format(stopDate1);     
Timestamp tm1 = new Timestamp(printFormat1.parse(timeString1).getTime());  This worked perfectly fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Use parse method to get Date Object and then construct Timestamp object.

```
 try {
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(printFormat.parse(timeString).getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LocalTime to store times (from a string and vice-versa) as shown below:

**Option(1): With Java8**

You can use Java8's LocalTime API for this, you can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)

```
String timeString = printFormat.format(stopDate1);
//Get your localTime object from timeString
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(timeString);
```

> static LocalTime  parse(CharSequence text) Obtains an instance of
>   LocalTime from a text string such as 10:15.

**Option(2): Without Java8**

You need to use jodatime library API, you can look [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

You can convert date object to Timestamp directly by

```
 Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(stopDate1.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for the timestamp of today's hh:mm then try this

```
static String todaysFtoTimestamp(String f){
    long todaystimestamp = ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 86400000 )  * 86400 );
    //System.out.println("today: " + todaystimestamp);
    long todaysftimestamp = Integer.parseInt(fToTimestamp(f)) + todaystimestamp;
    //System.out.println("todayF: " + todaysftimestamp);
    return todaysftimestamp+"";
}
static String fToTimestamp(String f){
    String[] fArray = f.split(":");
    String r = "null hehe";
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(fArray[0]);
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(fArray[1]);
    r = String.valueOf((minutes + (hours * 60))*60);
    return r ;
}
```